# How can i view already scheduled notifications in cordova-plugin-local-notification?

Tags: javascript, cordova, localnotification

I used cordova plugin local notification to set reminders in my app, it works fine, but can i view already scheduled notifications?. in my `README.md`, i can see getScheduled method, but it doesn't explain how to use it.

Comment: What does getScheduled() return? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var callbackIds = function (ids) {
                                     alert(ids);
                                    navigator.notification.alert(ids.length === 0 ? '- none -' : ids.join(' ,'));

                                };

                                getIds = function () {
                                    cordova.plugins.notification.local.getIds(callbackIds);
                                };

                                function getScheduledIds() {
                                    cordova.plugins.notification.local.getScheduledIds(callbackIds);
                                }


                                getTriggeredIds = function () {
                                    cordova.plugins.notification.local.getTriggeredIds(callbackIds);
                                };
```